# iOS Loading Dropbox Thumbnails in documents folder

Tags: ios, swift, thumbnails, dropbox

I'm encountering a problem when trying to download thumbnails with dropbox api. In fact, that thumbnails have to be put in a local folder (in my case the document folder) to get them later.

So here is the creation of the thumbnails folder in the document folder :

```
func createThumbnailsDirectory() -> String? {

    var paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths.objectAtIndex(0)
    var dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/thumbnails")

    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath)) {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
        return dataPath
    }
    else {
        return dataPath
    }
}
```

... that I'm using to stock images (with the name 'star.jpg' just for testing ) :

```
for file in dropboxMetadata.contents {
        if (file.thumbnailExists == true) {
            client.loadThumbnail(file.path, ofSize: "s", intoPath: thumbnailsDirectory + "star.jpg")
        }
    }
```

and then I print files in this folder :

```
println(NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(thumbnailsDirectory + "star.jpg", error: nil))
```

and it returns 'nil'. So I guess that there is a problem when loading thumbnails, but I can't get it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure you're implemented `loadedThumbnail` and `loadThumbnailFailedWithError`, and post the code and output.

Comment: The first method is already implemented, I reload my collection view inside. The second too but there is no error displayed in the console, only empty folder returning nil.

Comment: Can you have both of them log out the response (`metadata` or `error`) and then add the code and output to your question for reference?